# How to handle special characters like semi colons and quotation marks in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've created a CMS that takes text input. This is how the data is used when I grab it from the database.

```
echo "<img src=" . $row['image_url'] . " alt=" . $row['caption'] . ">";
```

Now the problem is, whenever there's a comma or a semi colon, php treats it as part of the code and the page ends up either not rendering well or completely breaking with errors like

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in`

I've tried using htmlspecialcase() when posting the data to the MySQL database but it didn't fix the problem.

EDIT: The main problem is with the alt part not the src part.

Comment: try this instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php. like this: addslashes($row['image_url']) that will escape all special chars in your strings.

Comment: there's no way that PHP would execute a form input, unless you're generating PHP code, or doing something silly like `eval()` on that code.

Comment: you can try these 2 ways <?php
echo "<img src=\"http://myimglink.com/img.png\" border=0>"; 

?>
// or 
<?php
echo '<img src="http://myimglink.com/img.png" border=0>'; 
?>

Comment: @MarcB it doesn't execute the form input. It only does that when I echo it from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using double quotes (`"`) to create a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) and in that string literal you want to use double quotes (`"`), then you may [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) those double quotes (`"`) to form a valid string.

```
echo "<img src=\"" . $row['image_url'] . "\" alt=\"" . $row['caption'] . "\">";
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the single quotes problem but it still doesn't work for double quotes or semi colons

Comment: Consider asking a separate question for each issue you have.

Comment: @digiwebguy If this answer worked for you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['image_url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $row['caption'];?> ">
```